# Rollup library ERROR in resolving fallback for shared module react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, rollup

I am creating a design system library with rollup and React 17.0.1, unfortunatelly I am getting this error when I use the library

```
Error: Can't resolve 'react/jsx-runtime'
```

The rollup file is this

```
export default [
    {
        input: "src/index.ts",
        output: [
            {
                file: packageJson.main,
                format: "cjs",
                exports: "auto",
                sourcemap: false,
                preserveModules: false
            },
            {
                file: packageJson.module,
                format: 'esm',
                sourcemap: false
            }
        ],
        plugins: [
            svgr(),
            json(),
            url(),
            peerDepsExternal(),
            resolve({
                jsnext: true,
                main: true,
                browser: true
            }),
            babel({
                babelrc: true,
                exclude: 'node_modules/**',
                presets: [
                    ["@babel/preset-react", { runtime: "automatic" }],
                ]
            }),
            commonjs({
                include: "node_modules/**",
                namedExports: {
                    'styled-components': [ 'styled', 'css', 'ThemeProvider' ],
                     "react/jsx-runtime": ["jsx", "jsxs", "Fragment"],
                     "react/jsx-dev-runtime": ["jsxDEV", "Fragment"]
                }
            }),
            typescript({ useTsconfigDeclarationDir: true }),
            postcss(),
            progress(),
            visualizer({})
        ],
        external: [...Object.keys(packageJson.peerDependencies || {})]
    },
    {
        input: 'types/index.d.ts',
        output: [{ file: 'dist/index.d.ts', format: "esm" }],
        external: [/\.css$/],
        plugins: [dts()],
    },
]
```

I looked for lots of solutions but I cannot find any good one... may you help me? Thanks
Lorenzo

Answer (score 0):

It may help. "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve" plugin.

```
resolve({ extensions: [".js", ".jsx"] })
```

(tsx and ts if you are using typescript)
please let me know if it didnt help :)